# Trying to get my grid go side by side instead of being stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid that is two columns and three rows. Right now i just have 1 big column i cant get them to go side by side.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "fox llama" "wolf pangolin" "marmoset panda";
}

.fox {
  grid-area: fox;
}

.llama {
  grid-area: llama;
}

.wolf {
  grid-area: wolf;
}

.marmoset {
  grid-area: marmoset;
}

.panda {
  grid-area: panda;
}

.pangolin {
  grid-area: pangolin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-background">
    <div class="fox">
      <h2 class="fox">FENNEC FOX</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/fennec-fox.jpg" alt="FENNEC FOX">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="llama">
      <h2 class="llama">LLAMA</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/llama.jpg" alt="LLAMA">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wolf">
      <h2 class="wolf">MANED WOLF</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/maned-wolf.jpg" alt="MANED WOLF">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="pangolin">
      <h2 class="pangolin">PANGOLIN</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/pangolin.jpg" alt="PANGOLIN">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="marmoset">
      <h2 class="marmoset">PYGMY MARMOSET</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/pygmy-marmoset.jpg" alt="PYGMY MARMOSET">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="panda">
      <h2 class="panda">RED PANDA</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/red-panda.jpg" alt="RED PANDA">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what i want the finished code to look like when it is correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omK6Q.jpg

Just adding more text because it says i have to even though i dont know what else to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `.main-background` inside of your `.container` with all the other elements in it. So the `.container` grid does not affect the elements but only the `.main-background`. Either move the `.main-background` out of the `.container` or use the `.main-background` as the grid. You could also close the `.main-backgound` inside the `.container` and position it absolute.

If you don't know how many rows your grid will have, you can use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`.

```css
.main-background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "fox llama"
    "wolf pangolin"
    "marmoset panda";
}

.fox {
  grid-area: fox;
}

.llama {
  grid-area: llama;
}

.wolf {
  grid-area: wolf;
}

.marmoset {
  grid-area: marmoset;
}

.panda {
  grid-area: panda;
}

.pangolin {
  grid-area: pangolin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-background">
    <div class="fox">
      <h2 class="fox">FENNEC FOX</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/fennec-fox.jpg" alt="FENNEC FOX" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="llama">
      <h2 class="llama">LLAMA</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/llama.jpg" alt="LLAMA" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="wolf">
      <h2 class="wolf">MANED WOLF</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/maned-wolf.jpg" alt="MANED WOLF" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pangolin">
      <h2 class="pangolin">PANGOLIN</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/pangolin.jpg" alt="PANGOLIN" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="marmoset">
      <h2 class="marmoset">PYGMY MARMOSET</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/pygmy-marmoset.jpg" alt="PYGMY MARMOSET" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="panda">
      <h2 class="panda">RED PANDA</h2>

      <img src="./assets/images/red-panda.jpg" alt="RED PANDA" />

      <p></p>

      <p class="TLM">
        TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is another container inside `.container`, which is `.main-background`. Your cards are inside that container, not `.container`. Just apply your styling to that instead.

Also, there is a lot of unnecessary code in your CSS, I would simplify it to just this:

```css
.main-background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-background">
    <div class="fox">
      <h2 class="fox">FENNEC FOX</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/fennec-fox.jpg" alt="FENNEC FOX">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="llama">
      <h2 class="llama">LLAMA</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/llama.jpg" alt="LLAMA">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="wolf">
      <h2 class="wolf">MANED WOLF</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/maned-wolf.jpg" alt="MANED WOLF">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="pangolin">
      <h2 class="pangolin">PANGOLIN</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/pangolin.jpg" alt="PANGOLIN">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="marmoset">
      <h2 class="marmoset">PYGMY MARMOSET</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/pygmy-marmoset.jpg" alt="PYGMY MARMOSET">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="panda">
      <h2 class="panda">RED PANDA</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/red-panda.jpg" alt="RED PANDA">
      <p></p>
      <p class="TLM">TO LEARN MORE <a href="#" target="_blank" class="CH">CLICK HERE</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```